# What are these requests that appear to be phoning home?

Tags: vulnerability, .net, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

I have a .NET 5 application running on AWS which has these requests constantly attempting to run:

`GET http://app-10-irules.com/`

`GET http://www.simpleexample.com/`

`GET http://ssl-app-default-backend.com/`

Currently they all 404, but nothing in my code references them. I reduced the application down to the bare-bones ASP.NET application with 0 routes, controllers etc., even less functional than a Hello World application. It occurs in .NET Core 3.1 as well, if I downgrade/upgrade between the two versions.

Comment: Hi yeahtheboys@! Cool username. I like the vibe. Looking at your post, I think more details are necessary. Have you done any WHOIS work on the domains? Does the application make the requests or does it receive the requests? Do you know when it started? What causes it to run? Does any of your static code reference these URLs? (And by way, be careful about trying to load unknown links outside of a sandbox.)

Comment: Those look like placeholder/example domains. Are they defaults that you need to override?

Comment: Where do you see such requests, i.e. are these done from the server or from the client. If seen on the client it might also be triggered by browser extensions etc, i.e. something outside your application.

Comment: Did you do a recursive grep for these in your source/libraries?

Comment: @securityOrange yes, only simpleexample is registered. There's nothing clearly identifying it as a malware site. The application makes the requests. It started when I upgraded from dotnet core 2.0 to dotnet core 3.1 (including associated library updates). The app running causes it to run (e.g. even if everything is stripped out, including all third-party libraries, it still occurs). None of my code references these URLs. Using, say, `strings` on the compiled DLLs and binaries doesn't show any of those URLs.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I cannot find any evidence that any of the libraries or the dotnet framework use those URLs as placeholders.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich on second examination, it looks like the requests are incoming, not outgoing. Perhaps it's an attempt to port-scan the application. Thank you all for your help, sorry for misleading you on the direction of the requests!

Comment: @yeahtheboys No need to apologize. :)